# Uncaught translation error: com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException requires --min-sdk-version >= 26

Tags: android, delphi, webrtc, firemonkey, dex

When i try in a blank delphi project to add this library :

https://bintray.com/google/webrtc/download_file?file_path=org%2Fwebrtc%2Fgoogle-webrtc%2F1.0.25331%2Fgoogle-webrtc-1.0.25331.aar

Then, when i compile the app and when delphi execute

> "C:\SDKs\android-sdk-windows\build-tools\28.0.3\dx.bat" --dex
>   --output="C:\FmxLiveChatVideo_source\Android\Debug\libwebrtc-dexed.jar"
>   "C:\lib\jar\org.webrtc\libwebrtc.jar"

I receive this error

> Uncaught translation error: com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: ERROR
>   in org.webrtc.Camera1Session.listenForTextureFrames:()V: invalid
>   opcode ba - invokedynamic requires --min-sdk-version >= 26 (currently
>   13)

Outside delphi, from the command line, if i add --min-sdk-version=26 to the line

> "C:\SDKs\android-sdk-windows\build-tools\28.0.3\dx.bat" --dex
>   --output="C:\FmxLiveChatVideo_source\Android\Debug\libwebrtc-dexed.jar"
>   "C:\lib\jar\org.webrtc\libwebrtc.jar"

then it's compile BUT now of course i can not deploy anymore the app to target lower than api 26 :(

As I understand, it's connected to the java version. Android in the past only supported Java code up to version 1.7 and seam we need 1.8. No idea what i can do :(

Comment: The Android manifest for the WebRTC aar file says: `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />`

Comment: @Brian ... yes minSdkVersion="16" it's OK, then i don't understand why I receive requires --min-sdk-version >= 26

Comment: There may be something that helps over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54589632/xamarin-android-binding-invalid-opcode - it's pretty much the same error. 
I haven't used Delphi in years, but the solution involves tweaking the build config to get the Android-delegated build aspect to play ball with Java v7 vs v8. 
It may be possible to port that solution to yours?