# Xamarin.Android binding invalid opcode

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Recently received a new Android SDK (aar) to bind in Xamarin. When initially starting the binding I receive the error

```
COMPILETODALVIK : Uncaught translation error : com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: invalid opcode ba (invokedynamic requires --min-sdk-version >= 26)
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This error is due to the SDK containing Java 8 (v1.8) byte code and it needs to be compatible with Java 7 (v1.7) to support lower API versions of Android.

In your Android project (not the binding project), add the following property.

```
<AndroidEnableDesugar>True</AndroidEnableDesugar>
```

or if you are in VS 2019+ you can turn on D8 which enables this by default.

```
<AndroidDexTool>d8</AndroidDexTool>
```

Desugaring is the process of allowing Java 8 byte code to be converted into Java 7 compatible byte code. This is a Google process that performs the conversion and is part of the Xamarin.Android build process.

Then if the SDK doesn't have any dependencies, it should all work. If you have EmbeddedReferenceJars, then things get more complicated.

In Visual Studio 2017 you will experience errors similar to

```
Error: java.lang.TypeNotPresentException :  Type io.reactivex.functions.Consumer not present
```

It will be unable to find these types in reference jars, because the desugaring processing isn't working properly. From Github Issues you eventually find the reason:

```
The first fix here is to add the `--classpath_entry` flag for every
`--input`, for some reason `Desugar` is not treating `--input` jars as
classpath entries
```

The bug is already tracked and fixed in Visual Studio 2019 Preview 2.

Now you switch to Visual Studio 2019 Preview 2 and you will come across this error.

```
Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/devtools/build/android/desugar/runtime/ThrowableExtension;
```

The desugaring processing is failing again because it needs this class to help communicate to the desugared code.

The class ThrowableExtension is actually found: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/src/tools/android/java/com/google/devtools/build/android/desugar/runtime/ThrowableExtension.java

You then take that Java class and you can compile it into a jar. A quick way to do it is copy that java file into a folder. Then inside that folder create a folder called `output`.

Call this command

```
javac -d ./output ThrowableExtension.java
```

Then move into the output directory and call this command

```
jar cvf desugar.jar *
```

It will create desugar.jar. Add that as an EmbeddedReferenceJar in your Android binding project. Your binding with Java 8 byte code with desugaring should now work.

Hopefully this might be resolved in a future Visual Studio version, so all these steps aren't necessary, but until then, at least you know what is happening and how to fix it.

Comment: Thank you very much Adam. I had the problem a month ago with the native WebRTC library and I fixed it by switching to VS2019 and using the last Xamarin.Android build but I couldn't solve the ThrowableExtension error.

Comment: Just to clear up some potential confusion: `<AndroidEnableDesugar>True</AndroidEnableDesugar>` by itself will use a very old version of `desugar.jar` that Google provided when they initially rolled out Java 8 Feature support in Android before the `dx` step. However using `<AndroidDexTool>d8</AndroidDexTool>` will use the latest and greatest version of `desugar` that is integrated into the `d8` dex compiler. In the future `d8` will become the default over `dx`.

Comment: Hey! I know it's odd to ask here, but i was reading your blog recently, specifically [this one](https://xamarinhelp.com/creating-xamarin-android-binding-library/). I have  a few question. `1. Can this be done for Xamarin.Forms as well? I mean can i reference the binding project from a Xamarin.Forms project?` and `2.I am about to use [this sdk](https://apps.epom.com/resources/sdk/Epom-Apps-SDK.zip). This SDK has many folders and the 'libs' folder contains .aar files. Should i only reference them? And as i read from your blog, i can't seem to find any .pom files. So, how do i get over this?`

Comment: @zackraiyan - It can be used with Xamarin.Forms, just reference the binding project from your Xamarin.Android project and call it the same as you would when you need to access native android apis. As for the pom. The Aar is just a zip file. Right click and unzip it, I think there should be a pom file inside there. If not, it normally comes from the developers that created the jar/aar in the first place.

Comment: @AdamPedley,i know i may be asking for too much, but can i contact you in other manner regarding xamarin, please? I am just starting out my project and after reading about the disastrous xamarin, i am really in fear that after i go a little further with the development, i may end up with no options but abandon the entire project. It's a big project and a lot of money is at stake. So, if you could please just answer a few of my questions, that would be very very helpful!

We can even chat on SO [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191182/xamarin-discussion)

Comment: @AdamPedley, hey, can you take a look at my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55520143/hide-title-bar-in-xamarin-android)

Comment: This really saved my day! I was going crazy and just changing from dx to d8 allowed my project to deploy and package!